# Why are HDMI to VGA with audio adapters common, while HDMI to DVI with audio not?

Tags: audio, hdmi, vga, dvi, adapter

I have a video game console that outputs video+audio through HDMI and a monitor that has a DVI and a VGA connector.

I do know that HDMI is backwards compatible with DVI, so HDMI to DVI cables are common.
In some cases DVI can also transmit audio, but it's rather rare and unusual, correct? So that means audio is lost when connecting a device outputing through HDMI to a display or TV or similar with DVI interface.

I tried to find on the internet some adapter that would have HDMI connector on one side (input) and DVI and a female 3.5 jack for my headphones on the other.
I found out that there are not that many on sale and the ones I found are bulky and expensive.
On the other side I found a lot of HDMI to VGA + audio adapters from different manufacturers, cheap and rather small. One example:

http://www.delock.com/produkte/S_65587/merkmale.html

How is this possible? HDMI to VGA + audio jack involves separating the video and audio signals from HDMI and then converting both signals to analog. Quite complicated process.

While HDMI to DVI + audio jack would require no video signal manipulation at all, only extraction of audio and conversion of it to analog.

I don't get it.

EDIT: Basically what I don't understand is why there isn't a product that combines the small dimensions of the product mentioned above (item 65587) and a simple HDMI to DVI cable. Basically item 65587 but with DVI instead of VGA, everything else the same. Right now you only have HDMI audio extractors or HDMI to DVI+audio - both bulky with an AC adapter needed.

Comment: Simply use a [*HDMI audio extractor*](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=HDMI+audio+extractor&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) unit and a HDMI-to-DVI plug adapter.  Strangely enough, the first shopping entry is exactly what you claim is rare: http://www.monoprice.com/Product?p_id=8124&gclid=CNWI5Z3uq9ACFY9bfgodHvIPDg

Comment: I am aware of that. But again - bulky and not cheap. And needs power. How are HDMI to VGA + analog audio smaller, need no power and cheaper if it's a more complicated process?

Comment: *"Cheap"* is relative and a value judgment.  The example converter you cite is inferior to the one I use; my HDMI-to-VGA converter supports HDCP.

Comment: BTW the DVI connector by itself is "bulkier" and more expensive than either a HDMI or HD15 connector.

Comment: The DVI connector might be bulkier, but I still don't understand the technical aspects:
HDMI to VGA + 3.5 audio jack adapters exist in a small package, not needing an AC adapter.
While HDMI audio extractors or HDMI to DVI + audio are bulkier (more complex hardware inside) and needing an AC adapter.
First case is more complex, no?

Comment: Yes, HDMI-to-VGA is more "complex", but ***economics rule***.  Apparently there is demand for HDMI-to-VGA conversion, and that is driving new development for smaller, lower-power, and cheaper converter chips.  The fact that the Chrontel CH7101 chip in that example converter is available in both ***commercial*** and ***industrial*** versions indicate that that chip was developed for applications other than that dongle (i.e. consumer-grade products use cheap parts, not industrial-rated).  Very likely the CH7101 chip is used in an industrial or non-PC high-volume computer/video product.

Answer (score 1):

You find more HDMI to VGA than HDMI to DVI because VGA was more widely used than DVI. A lot of monitors included only a VGA input while, often, DVI inputs come with another VGA or even an HDMI. Therefore, if you had to build a backward-compatibility interface you would probably choose to work with VGA.

Comment: Thanks.
But I still don't understand how can you have a digital (HDMI) to analog (VGA + 3.5 jack) converter being in a smaller package, without the need for an AC adapter.
While a HDMI audio extractor or a HDMI to DVI + audio being bulkier and needing an AC adapter.
When clearly the first process is more complicated.

Comment: I confess I don't know, but probably it is due to the fact that in order to convert signal from HDMI to DVI+audio you have to power up the signal, maybe because the HDMI output doesn't provide enough voltage for it, while VGA+audio is less power-demanding.

Comment: *"I confess I don't know, but ..."* -- You should have stopped there instead of making a ridiculous guess disguised as a *"fact"*.